# Displaying Maps inside Android app using HTML5

Tags: android, html, dictionary

Is it possible to display the Maps inside a div on a html5 android app?  I am able to get the longitude and latitude but I just can't find a way to view the coordinates without calling the Maps app.

Please help.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [Google JavaScript API v3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/)?

This [javascript / jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) makes life with Google Maps so much easier. See his cool [demos + code](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-mobile-example.html).

See Android / PhoneGap tutorials on [route finding](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt4part1) and [marker placement](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt4p2).